# Samba client not working Ubuntu 18.04, need help

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing, client

I am using Samba client to try to view shared directories residing on a Windows-10 64 bit machine from Linux.  The samba is installed on my xUbuntu 18.04 64 bit laptop. XUbuntu is just like regular Ubuntu except that it uses the XFCE desktop which I like.   I have made some changes to my /etc/samba/smb.conf but am unclear on exactly what needs to be done.

Both computers are part of the "FSI" workgroup.  I start the services smbd and nmbd.  Then from a file explorer on the Linux laptop I can go to the FSI workgroup and see the Windows machine {named "TIBERIUS"}  as well as the Linux laptop named {"XENOBA-LIN"}.  But I can't go and see the shared directory or any directories on TIBERIUS.  When both machines are re-booted into Windows I can.

I do NOT want the Linux laptop to be the server as it's only intermittently on the network.  The windows machine should be the primary nameserver and server.
This is an abbreviated copy of my smb.conf on the Linux machine.

/etc/samba/smb.conf

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================
[global]
## Browsing/Identification ###
# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = FSI

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
   wins support = yes

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
#   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####
### note IP 192.168.1.72 is for Tiberius: the remote Windows machine  ####
### anyhow it's commented out I think  ###
;   interfaces = 192.168.1.72/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
;   bind interfaces only = yes
####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

############ Misc ############
# all the usual defaults here except when listed

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes
```

I'll also attach a screenshot

[image: Workgroup found thats as far as I can get]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I can't go and see the shared directory or any directories on
> TIBERIUS
>
> I do NOT want the Linux laptop to be the server as it's only
> intermittently on the network.

There is a bug in the gvfs backend ( gvfsd-smb-browse ) of your file manager that attempts to access the Win10 host and its share using a dialect of smb ( smb1 ) that Win10 has disabled.

That does not mean you cannot access the Win10 server - you just have to bypass the bug by asking for the host explicitly by its mDNS host name and share name in Thunar:

```
smb://tiberius.local/share-name
```

The `.local` part is something Win10 can now do by default.

Comment: Thanks @kyodake  and Morbius1    This worked after I explicitly typed out the path smb://TIBERIUS/k_share      That's a nasty bug in disabling the smb1.

Answer (score 1):

The Samba configuration file can be confusing.

I show you how to use a graphical tool (system-config-samba) to set up Samba server.

Install the Samba server suite from Ubuntu repository by running the following command in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba samba-common-bin
```

To start these two services, issue the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl start smbd
sudo systemctl start nmbd
```

Now run the following command to install system-config-samba

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

Create a Samba user, replace username with your preferred username

```
sudo adduser username
```

Set a password for the new user,You can press Enter to answer the remaining questions

Also need to set a separate Samba password for the user.

```
sudo smbpasswd -a username
```

Start system-config-samba, run the following command

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

In the Samba GUI, click Preferences ---> Server Settings menu.

Make sure the value of workgroup is the same with the workgroup settings of Windows computers.

Then click the plus button to create a Samba share, and in the Basic tab, specify

```
The directory/folder you want to share
The share name
A description of the share
Whether the remote user can write to the Samba share or not
Whether other computers in your network can see the Samba share or not
```

In the Access tab, select the Samba user you just created and click OK.

If the Samba user isn’t displayed, please restart system-config-samba.

If you select Allow access to everyone, then others in the same network
can access the shared folder without entering a username and password.

You  quickly share a folder using Samba with Thunar without requiring root access.

Comment: Thank very much kyodake.  After I explicitly typed out the path  smb://TIBERIUS/k_share   it worked!